# What is the correct XPath for choosing attributes that contain "foo"?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML, what XPath returns all elements whose `prop` attribute contains `Foo` (the first three nodes):

```
<bla>
 <a prop="Foo1"/>
 <a prop="Foo2"/>
 <a prop="3Foo"/>
 <a prop="Bar"/>
</bla>
```

Comment: Why is everyone looking at the "prop" attribute? Did I miss something? It just says get the first three nodes.

Comment: Everyone is looking at the prop attribute because that's what was asked. Get all nodes where prop contains "Foo". 

Add <a prop="Foo5" /> and you will see why it isn't just "the first three nodes"..

Comment: The question in the body is poorly worded, regardless of the title. Can foo really be in any prop attribute, or do you seriously just want the first three nodes?

Comment: Yes, refer to the title please (and feel free to edit).

Comment: If you need case-insensitive comparison see  [find-an-element-whose-attribute-contains-a-text-case-insensitively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604057/xpath-to-find-an-element-whose-attribute-contains-a-text-case-insensitively)

Comment: very good link when using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 381, accepted):

```
//a[contains(@prop,'Foo')]
```

Works if I use this XML to get results back.

```
<bla>
 <a prop="Foo1">a</a>
 <a prop="Foo2">b</a>
 <a prop="3Foo">c</a>
 <a prop="Bar">a</a>
</bla>
```

Edit: 
Another thing to note is that while the XPath above will return the correct answer for that particular xml, if you want to guarantee you only get the "a" elements in element "bla", you should as others have mentioned also use

```
/bla/a[contains(@prop,'Foo')]
```

This will search you all "a" elements in your entire xml document, regardless of being nested in a "blah" element

```
//a[contains(@prop,'Foo')]
```

I added this for the sake of thoroughness and in the spirit of stackoverflow. :)

Comment: `xmlme.com` now redirects to some other host and does not appear to host the tool or anything like it.

Comment: This isn't working. I still get everything: `xidel http://popurls.com/ --extract '//a[contains(@href,'/go/pop')]/@href'`

Answer (score 32):

This XPath will give you all nodes that have attributes containing 'Foo' regardless of node name or attribute name:

```
//attribute::*[contains(., 'Foo')]/..
```

Of course, if you're more interested in the contents of the attribute themselves, and not necessarily their parent node, just drop the /..

```
//attribute::*[contains(., 'Foo')]
```

Comment: For all nodes `//@*[contains(., 'Foo')]`

Comment: For additional information, @ is an Abbrev for attribute. E.g: `@href` is short for `attribute::href`

Answer (score 16):

```
descendant-or-self::*[contains(@prop,'Foo')]
```

Or:

```
/bla/a[contains(@prop,'Foo')]
```

Or:

```
/bla/a[position() <= 3]
```

Dissected:

```
descendant-or-self::
```

The Axis - search through every node underneath and the node itself. It is often better to say this than //. I have encountered some implementations where // means anywhere (decendant or self of the root node). The other use the default axis.

```
* or /bla/a
```

The Tag - a wildcard match, and /bla/a is an absolute path.

```
[contains(@prop,'Foo')] or [position() <= 3]
```

The condition within [ ]. @prop is shorthand for attribute::prop, as attribute is another search axis. Alternatively you can select the first 3 by using the position() function.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried something like:

//a[contains(@prop, "Foo")]

I've never used the contains function before but suspect that it should work as advertised...

Comment: @toddk... you've targeted a non-existant attribute: @foo. You'd want to target @prop ;-)

Answer (score 6):

John C is the closest, but XPath is case sensitive, so the correct XPath would be:

```
/bla/a[contains(@prop, 'Foo')]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you also need to match the content of the link itself, use text():

`//a[contains(@href,"/some_link")][text()="Click here"]`

Answer (score 2):

/bla/a[contains(@prop, "foo")]

Answer (score 2):

try this:

//a[contains(@prop,'foo')]

that should work for any "a" tags in the document

Answer (score 1):

For the code above...
//*[contains(@prop,'foo')]

Comment: this is for any element with foo in, but the attribute must be "prop"

Answer (score 0):

you can also use it as :

`a[@class='specific-class-name' and contains(@href,'/link/to/something')]`

this means a tag a that have an attribute href that contains a specific words
don't forget to use **@** before attribute name