# xpath: find a node that has a given attribute whose value contains a string

Tags: xml, xpath, contains

Is there an xpath way to find a node that has a given attribute whose value contains a given string?

For example I have an xml document and want to find a node where the `address` attribute contains the string `Downing`, so that I could find the following node:

```
<person name="blair" address="10 Downing St. London"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct XPath for choosing attributes that contain "foo"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103325/what-is-the-correct-xpath-for-choosing-attributes-that-contain-foo)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
select="//*[contains(@address,'Downing')]"
```

Comment: Tested with Notepad++ XML Tools, returns the node fine. Good job.

Comment: Remember to avoid the '//' if possible. :-) Good job though.

Comment: @Jweede yeah, I know. But as the node wasn't specified, I assumed that he wants every node with that attribute.

Comment: Been looking all over for a way to do "like" style searching for the value of an attribute. Thanks!