# Extract items list from XML in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

In python, what is the best way to extract the list of items from the following xml?

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="__anonymous__admin@localhost/8978528613056092673206" 
 from="conference.localhost" id="disco" type="result">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
        <item jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
        <item jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

I usually use lxml with xpath, but it's not working in this case. I think my problems are due to namespaces. I'm not set on lxml and am open to using any library.

I would like a solution that is robust enough to fail if the general structure of the xml changes.

Comment: Maybe you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953761/accessing-xmlns-attribute-with-python-elementree

Comment: What information do you want to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `lxml` but you can use an expression like `//*[local-name()="item"]` to pull out the `item` elements regardless of their namespace.

You might also want to take a look at [Amara](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Amara/2.0a4) for XML processing.

```
>>> import amara.bindery
>>> doc = amara.bindery.parse(
...     '''<iq xmlns="jabber:client" 
...          to="__anonymous__admin@localhost/8978528613056092673206"
...          from="conference.localhost" id="disco" type="result">
...          <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
...            <item jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
...            <item jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
...          </query>
...        </iq>''')
>>> for item in doc.iq.query.item:
...   print item.jid, item.name
...
pgatt@conference.localhost pgatt (1)
pgatt@conference.localhost pgatt (1)
>>>
```

Once I discovered Amara, I would never consider processing XML any other way.

Comment: Thanks. `//*[local-name()="item"]` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Interesting, have you had any cause to complain about speed with this library?

Comment: @MattH - not really.  It isn't blazingly fast but I haven't had any complaints thus far.  With the ease of use, I'll find ways to exploit caches before I could go back to any of the other libs.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question earlier about how to parse and search through xml data.

[Full text searching XML data with Python: best practices, pros & cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790943/full-text-searching-xml-data-with-python-best-practices-pros-cons/5890425#5890425)

You'll want to look at the xml2json function.
The function expects a minidom object. This is how I got my xml, not sure how you do it.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
x = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
json = xml2json(x)
```

Or if you use a string and not a url:

```
x = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
json = xml2json(x)
```

The xml2json function will then return a dictionary with all values found in the xml. You may have to try it out and print the output to see what the layout looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I've missed the boat, but here's how you do it while caring about namespaces.

You can either spell them all out in the query, or make yourself a namespace map which you pass to the xpath query.

```
from lxml import etree

data = """<iq xmlns="jabber:client" to="__anonymous__admin@localhost/8978528613056092673206"
 from="conference.localhost" id="disco" type="result">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
        <item jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
        <item jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
    </query>
</iq>"""

nsmap = {
  'jc': "jabber:client",
  'di':"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"
}

doc = etree.XML(data)

for item in doc.xpath('//jc:iq/di:query/di:item',namespaces=nsmap):
  print etree.tostring(item).strip()
  print "Name: %s\nJabberID: %s\n" % (item.attrib.get('name'),item.attrib.get('jid'))
```

Produces:

```
<item xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
Name: pgatt (1)
JabberID: pgatt@conference.localhost

<item xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" jid="pgatt@conference.localhost" name="pgatt (1)"/>
Name: pgatt (1)
JabberID: pgatt@conference.localhost
```