# Get the nodes containg an attribute with a certain value in XML in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

i want to find nodes containg an attribute with a certain value in XML . I tried with a certain Xpath expression but it wont work..

```
String expression = ".*[@*[starts-with(., '"+search+"')]]";
```

Here the `search` is the variable which contains the value which i want to search. Can anyone tell me the right Xpath expression.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xpath: find a node that has a given attribute whose value contains a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614797/xpath-find-a-node-that-has-a-given-attribute-whose-value-contains-a-string)

Comment: Its not quite what i want..I want to search for the values in the xml attributes..Suppose attribute names are not concerned..

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is correct, only the `.*` makes no sense.

```
String expression = "//*[@*[starts-with(., '"+search+"')]]";
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak..It was my ignorance..

After a long and hard trying out i found an answer myself.but dont know the efficient factor of the query but it gives the result as i wanted.If there is a better one please let me know.


    String expression ="//*[starts-with(@*,'"+search+"')] | //"+search+"";

Comment: Depending on what you want to do this is exactly what you need. ;)