# How to get HTML5 data attribute using xpath?

Tags: java, ruby, xpath, selenium-webdriver, capybara

How do I get the first table (table1) using xpath for Webdriver?

```
<span id="dynamically generated id" data-id="table1">
  <table>
  ...
  </table>
</span>

<span id="dynamically generated id" data-id="table2">
  <table>
  ...
  </table>
</span>
```

I am able to get all `data-id` elements but I want to filter within it for text `table1` to get the exact element.

This did not work!

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//@*[starts-with(name(),'data-id') [contains(text(),'table1')]]"));
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answering my own question...This appears to get the exact element.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-id='table1']"))
```

Comment: this may work but generally for automation testing on projects undergoing development it may not be good practice since if any changes are made to the dom on that specific page your xpath will most likely change and you'll have to re-write the test cases

Answer (score 36):

You get the table like this:

```
//span[@data-id='table1']/table
```

Select the `data-id` attribute and get the child element of name `table`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can also use the `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-id='table1']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try (built this be combining [xpath: find a node that has a given attribute whose value contains a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614797/xpath-find-a-node-that-has-a-given-attribute-whose-value-contains-a-string) and [Getting attribute using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531995/getting-attribute-from-xpath))

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-id, 'table1')]/@data-id"));
```