# Xpath selector for class

Tags: css, xpath

I want to get the Xpath selector for classname(.class) . So basically, i want to know how I can select [attr~=value]

So if i have an element

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
```

I want to select .class1, it should return both the divs. [@class='class1'] doesn't work since it won't select the first div.

Comment: //div[contains(@class,'class1')]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103325/what-is-the-correct-xpath-for-choosing-attributes-that-contain-foo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find an element by CSS class with XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604471/how-can-i-find-an-element-by-css-class-with-xpath)

Comment: @mazzucci: That would match `div.class123`

Comment: Yes, that is true. So he would need something more advanced.

Comment: Contains will match class123 and fasfasjfhkkdsjfjkclass1 as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That trick should only find "class1":

```
//div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' class1 ')]
```

Comment: Well I know this one. I was looking for a more elegant solution, but I  guess there isn't any

Comment: This is XPath, we don't do "elegant" :-)  Seriously, this is the best technique.