# XPath to find an element whose attribute contains a text, case-insensitively?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
    <root>
// other nodes
    <a href="/PatternFramework/Pages/LogOut.aspx?np=/sites/novatestsite/Home.aspx" slick-uniqueid="92">Sign out</a>
    </root>
```

How to write an xpath which returns the `a` tag whose `href` contains "logout.aspx"?

For instance something like

```
//a[@href[contains[., "logout.aspx"]]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Case-sensitive:

```
//a[contains(@href,'logout.aspx')]
```

Case-insensitive for XPath 2.0:

```
//a[contains(lower-case(@href),'logout.aspx')]
```

Case-insensitive for XPath 1.0:

```
//a[contains(translate(@href, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'logout.aspx')]
```

Comment: Who is it? Which xpath-provider used?

Comment: bit-101.com/xpath is old tool from 2006 year. use http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php

Comment: ah, my original text had "LogOut". how to make it case in-sensitive? I mean to ignore the case sensitivity?

Comment: this is not case-insensitive, this is just lower-case.

Comment: @nicolimo86 Full case-insensitive variant: //a[contains(lower-case(@href),lower-case('LogOut.aspx'))]