# xpath lowercase - Is there xpath function to do this?

Tags: xml, xpath

For example, for the xml below

```
<REPORT ID="TimekeeperListEdited" BoundId="Timekeeper" BoundType="ReportObject" />
```

How to match the first  record with xpath like `//*[@BoundId='TimeKeeper']`. Is there xpath function to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write an xpath to find an element whose attribute contains a text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604057/how-to-write-an-xpath-to-find-an-element-whose-attribute-contains-a-text)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using **XPath 2.0**, you can use the `lower-case()` function:

```
//*[lower-case(@BoundId) = 'timekeeper']
```

In case your use is restricted to **XPath 1.0**, you can convert cases with the `translate()` function which replaces each character in your string (first argument) that matches any character in the second argument, with the character that occurs *in the same position* in the string passed as the third argument:

```
//*[translate(@BoundId, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'timekeeper']
```

or, if you are dealing with a particular case and the string you are testing is *fixed* (and not a variable coming from some other part in your program), you can simply translate the characters that interest you:

```
//*[translate(@BoundId, 'k', 'K') = 'TimeKeeper']
```