# Xpath - selecting nearest element after plain text

Tags: xpath

Let's say we have the following structure :

```
some text
<img src="#" />
sdfsdf
sdfsdf

plaintext-identificator-123

<img src="1" /> //get
<img src="2" /> //get
<img src="3" /> //not get
```

I need to get the nearest 2  elements after "plaintext-identificator-123".

In this case, the desired result would be to get 2  elements with srcs 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways:

`//text()[contains(., 'plaintext-identificator-123')]/following-sibling::img[position()<3]`

Comment: How would you make this case-insensitive? The "plaintext-identificator-123".

Comment: What version of xpath are you using?

Comment: That works perfectly. I have one final question. If i wanted to use another condition, which on top of that would select all links which have given case in-sensitive keyword in href attribute or in link text.

Comment: You need to use the same approach. You use `contains` where at the place of "what should contain" you use `translate` function that would translate your attribute to lowercase.

Comment: @TadeášJílek in other words you change the `.` in my current example to `@href` or whatever attribute holding your keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your actual structure and see if it works (it works for your sample in the question):

```
(//img['plaintext-identificator-123']/following-sibling::img)[position()<3]
```

if you want the attribute values of the `src` attribute of the target `img` nodes, change it to:

```
(//img['plaintext-identificator-123']/following-sibling::img)[position()<3]/@src
```

Edit:

Following the comments below, try this:

```
(//text()[contains(.,'plaintext-identificator-123')]/preceding-sibling::img/following-sibling::img)[position()<3]/@src
```

Use http://xpather.com/DOJz7nl1 (try it with and without the indentificator).

Comment: Yeah, but that absolutely ignores the "after plaintext-identificator-123" condition.

Comment: And if you wanted to make the xpath case in-sensitive, meaning the "identificator" text would be case in-sensitive.

Comment: @TadeášJílek That makes things more complicated and, if it's important, may be worth posting as a separate question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183701/xpath-lowercase-is-there-xpath-function-to-do-this.

Comment: I'm testing it and it does select the right elements, but ignores the identificator text. Look. http://xpather.com/pORxec5p