# Convert String to lowercase in mediation sequece WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have scenario where I want to convert string to lowercase inside mediation sequence. Mediation sequence I have is as follows

```
<property name=":: ID::" expression="get-property('Id')"/>
```

I want to convert the ID to lowercase. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on whether you have **XPath 2.0** support configured in your product, you can use: `lower-case()` function:

```
<property name=":: ID::" expression="lower-case(get-property('Id'))"/>
```

If you are restricted to **XPath 1.0**, you can convert with the `translate()` function like below:

```
<property name=":: ID::" expression="translate(get-property('Id'), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
```

Something more you can read in this topic [xpath lowercase - Is there xpath function to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183701/xpath-lowercase-is-there-xpath-function-to-do-this/24184571)