# what is the way to locate an element which has dynamic id?? Even if Xpath & CSS is not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working with a dynamic website, ID is available with dynamic guid. Could any one explain me how can I write manual xpath to find an element in the website?

```
   <input id="JointInsureds_1e124dce-7492-4315-b1d8-7b806babd994__ForeName" 
        type="text" 
        value="" name="JointInsureds[1e124dce-7492-4315-b1d8-7b806babd994].ForeName"   
        maxlength="20"
        data-val-required="The First Name field is required." 
        data-val-length-max="20" 
        data-val-length="The field First Name must be a string with a maximum length of 20." 
        data-val="true"/>
```

Comment: Did you try any of the XPath functions like [contains](http://stackoverflow.com/a/103417/2101267)?

Answer (score 1):

With CSS, you can use:

```
input[id^='JointInsureds'][$='ForeName']
```

In CSS, you can handle dynamic elements using:

```
*=  - contains
^=  - starts with
$=  - ends with
~=  - contains (space seperated)
```

With XPath, you can use:

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'JointInsureds')][ends-with(@id, 'ForeName')]
```

(*don't quote me on the xpath, it might need some revision. it's been years since i've used it because css is perfectly capable for tasks like this*)